# Website Visitor (Visited URL) Logger Application

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I have made an application to log all websites visited by current PC user. This is not for a malicious use. I am making this feature for my employee monitoring software which will be licensed under proper laws.

Coming on main point, Whenever I am fetching URL from any browser such as IE. I am only getting its URL for all opened tabs. I am unable to get any tab handle for IE7+ , because of which I am unable to maintain a list of tabs for which I have already logged URL's for same tab.
Below is my code (Take a Look on Commented Code First):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WebsiteLoggerConsole
{
    public class WebLogger
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint     lpdwProcessId);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent,
                                                  IntPtr hwndChildAfter,
                                                  string lpszClass,
                                                  string lpszWindow);

        System.Threading.Timer log;
        public void StartLoggin()
        {
            try
            {
                TimerCallback logcallback = new TimerCallback(LogTick);
                log = new System.Threading.Timer(logcallback, null, 0, 2000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void StopLogging()
        {
            try
            {
                log.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public void LogTick(Object stateInfo)
        {
            CreateLog();
        }

        void CreateLog()
        {
            try
            {
                SHDocVw.ShellWindows shellWindows = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();
                string filename;

                foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie in shellWindows)
                {
                    filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ie.FullName).ToLower();
                    if (filename.Equals("iexplore"))
                    {
                        int val = ie.HWND;
                        IntPtr hwnd = new IntPtr(val);
                        IntPtr uihwnd = GetDirectUIHWND(hwnd);
                        string ddd = (ie.LocationURL) + " :::: " + (uihwnd.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine(ddd);
                    }
                }

                //SHDocVw.ShellWindows shellWindows = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();
                //string filename;

                //foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie in shellWindows)
                //{
                //    filename =     Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ie.FullName).ToLower();
                //    if (filename.Equals("iexplore"))
                //    {
                //        int val = ie.HWND;
                //        IntPtr hwnd = new IntPtr(val);
                //        IntPtr uihwnd = GetDirectUIHWND(hwnd);
                //        IntPtr tabhwnd = GetDirectUIHWND(uihwnd);
                //        string ddd = (ie.LocationURL) + " :::: " +     (tabhwnd.ToString());
                //        Console.WriteLine(ddd);
                //    }
                //}

                //Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
                //foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
                //{
                //    if (theprocess.ProcessName == "iexplore")
                //    {
                //        Console.WriteLine("Process: {0}, ID: {1}, Handle: {3}, Window     name: {2}",
                //            theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id,     theprocess.MainWindowTitle, theprocess.SessionId.ToString()
                //        );
                //    }
                //}
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private static IntPtr GetDirectUIHWND(IntPtr ieFrame)
        {
            // try IE 9 first:
            IntPtr intptr = FindWindowEx(ieFrame, IntPtr.Zero, "WorkerW", null);
            if (intptr == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                // IE8 and IE7
                intptr = FindWindowEx(ieFrame, IntPtr.Zero, "CommandBarClass", null);
            }
            intptr = FindWindowEx(intptr, IntPtr.Zero, "ReBarWindow32", null);
            //intptr = FindWindowEx(intptr, IntPtr.Zero, "TabBandClass", null);
            //intptr = FindWindowEx(intptr, IntPtr.Zero, "DirectUIHWND", null);
            return intptr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please look at commented code so that you will get an Idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I provided a solution on this topic: [How to write a standalone URL logger for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849771/how-to-write-a-standalone-url-logger-for-windows/16850017)

There I used Java, but you can do the same by using C#. I am almost sure there is a lot of good libpcap wrappers for C#.

There is a project called pcapDotNet and you can use it.

Adjusting one example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PcapDotNet.Core;
using PcapDotNet.Packets;
using PcapDotNet.Packets.IpV4;
using PcapDotNet.Packets.Transport;

namespace InterpretingThePackets
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Retrieve the device list from the local machine
            IList<LivePacketDevice> allDevices = LivePacketDevice.AllLocalMachine;

            if (allDevices.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No interfaces found! Make sure WinPcap is installed.");
                return;
            }

            // Print the list
            for (int i = 0; i != allDevices.Count; ++i)
            {
                LivePacketDevice device = allDevices[i];
                Console.Write((i + 1) + ". " + device.Name);
                if (device.Description != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(" (" + device.Description + ")");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(" (No description available)");
            }

            int deviceIndex = 0;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the interface number (1-" + allDevices.Count + "):");
                string deviceIndexString = Console.ReadLine();
                if (!int.TryParse(deviceIndexString, out deviceIndex) ||
                    deviceIndex < 1 || deviceIndex > allDevices.Count)
                {
                    deviceIndex = 0;
                }
            } while (deviceIndex == 0);

            // Take the selected adapter
            PacketDevice selectedDevice = allDevices[deviceIndex - 1];

            // Open the device
            using (PacketCommunicator communicator = 
                selectedDevice.Open(65536,                                  // portion of the packet to capture
                                                                            // 65536 guarantees that the whole packet will be captured on all the link layers
                                    PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, // promiscuous mode
                                    1000))                                  // read timeout
            {
                // Check the link layer. We support only Ethernet for simplicity.
                if (communicator.DataLink.Kind != DataLinkKind.Ethernet)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This program works only on Ethernet networks.");
                    return;
                }

                // Compile the filter
                using (BerkeleyPacketFilter filter = communicator.CreateFilter("ip and tcp"))
                {
                    // Set the filter
                    communicator.SetFilter(filter);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Listening on " + selectedDevice.Description + "...");

                // start the capture
                communicator.ReceivePackets(0, PacketHandler);
            }
        }

        // Callback function invoked by libpcap for every incoming packet
        private static void PacketHandler(Packet packet)
        {
            // print timestamp and length of the packet
            Console.WriteLine(packet.Timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff") + " length:" + packet.Length);

            IpV4Datagram ip = packet.Ethernet.IpV4;

            //Do your magic here using HttpRequestDatagram
        }
    }
}
```