# How to write a standalone URL logger for Windows?

Tags: network-programming, packet-sniffers

I want to write a program to log all the URLs visited on a computer, but standalone, so not as a Fiddler2 extension. Are there any libraries out there that do this already that I could include in my application (which I was intending to write in C# .Net, but I'm flexible as long as it's for Windows)? If not are there any that could at least facilitate reading information from HTTP packets? I want to analyse the urls on the fly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you would have to sniff the traffic on the computer under analysis.

To achieve this, use pcap library. As you may want to use a higher level programming language as C# (or Java), there are a lot of wrappers available to facilitate the usage of pcap library. In Java (since I am more used to it), there is one wrapper called jNetPcap. It is open source and has a good documentation. See the example below to sniff the traffic of any of our NICs:

```
package org.jnetpcap.examples;  
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.Date;  
import java.util.List;  

import org.jnetpcap.Pcap;  
import org.jnetpcap.PcapIf;  
import org.jnetpcap.packet.PcapPacket;  
import org.jnetpcap.packet.PcapPacketHandler;  

/** 
 * Here is the output generated by this example : 
 *  
 *  Network devices found: 
 *  #0: \Device\NPF_{BC81C4FC-242F-4F1C-9DAD-EA9523CC992D} [Intel(R) PRO/100 VE]  
 *  #1: \Device\NPF_{E048DA7F-D007-4EEF-909D-4238F6344971} [VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter] 
 *  #2: \Device\NPF_{5B62B373-3EC1-460D-8C71-54AA0BF761C7} [VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter] 
 *  #3: \Device\NPF_GenericDialupAdapter [Adapter for generic dialup and VPN capture] 
 *  
 *  Choosing 'Intel(R) PRO/100 VE) ' on your behalf: 
 *  Received packet at Tue Nov 03 18:52:42 EST 2009 caplen=1362 len=1362 jNetPcap rocks! 
 *  Received packet at Tue Nov 03 18:52:45 EST 2009 caplen=82   len=82   jNetPcap rocks! 
 *  Received packet at Tue Nov 03 18:52:45 EST 2009 caplen=145  len=145  jNetPcap rocks! 
 *  Received packet at Tue Nov 03 18:52:45 EST 2009 caplen=62   len=62   jNetPcap rocks! 
 *  Received packet at Tue Nov 03 18:52:45 EST 2009 caplen=164  len=164  jNetPcap rocks! 
 *  Received packet at Tue Nov 03 18:52:45 EST 2009 caplen=62   len=62   jNetPcap rocks! 
 *  Received packet at Tue Nov 03 18:52:45 EST 2009 caplen=54   len=54   jNetPcap rocks! 
 *  Received packet at Tue Nov 03 18:52:45 EST 2009 caplen=1073 len=1073 jNetPcap rocks! 
 *  Received packet at Tue Nov 03 18:52:45 EST 2009 caplen=1514 len=1514 jNetPcap rocks! 
 *  Received packet at Tue Nov 03 18:52:45 EST 2009 caplen=279  len=279  jNetPcap rocks! 
 */  
public class ClassicPcapExample {  

    /** 
     * Main startup method 
     *  
     * @param args 
     *          ignored 
     */  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        List<PcapIf> alldevs = new ArrayList<PcapIf>(); // Will be filled with NICs  
        StringBuilder errbuf = new StringBuilder(); // For any error msgs  

        /*************************************************************************** 
         * First get a list of devices on this system 
         **************************************************************************/  
        int r = Pcap.findAllDevs(alldevs, errbuf);  
        if (r == Pcap.NOT_OK || alldevs.isEmpty()) {  
            System.err.printf("Can't read list of devices, error is %s", errbuf  
                .toString());  
            return;  
        }  

        System.out.println("Network devices found:");  

        int i = 0;  
        for (PcapIf device : alldevs) {  
            String description =  
                (device.getDescription() != null) ? device.getDescription()  
                    : "No description available";  
            System.out.printf("#%d: %s [%s]\n", i++, device.getName(), description);  
        }  

        PcapIf device = alldevs.get(0); // We know we have atleast 1 device  
        System.out  
            .printf("\nChoosing '%s' on your behalf:\n",  
                (device.getDescription() != null) ? device.getDescription()  
                    : device.getName());  

        /*************************************************************************** 
         * Second we open up the selected device 
         **************************************************************************/  
        int snaplen = 64 * 1024;           // Capture all packets, no trucation  
        int flags = Pcap.MODE_PROMISCUOUS; // capture all packets  
        int timeout = 10 * 1000;           // 10 seconds in millis  
        Pcap pcap =  
            Pcap.openLive(device.getName(), snaplen, flags, timeout, errbuf);  

        if (pcap == null) {  
            System.err.printf("Error while opening device for capture: "  
                + errbuf.toString());  
            return;  
        }  

        /*************************************************************************** 
         * Third we create a packet handler which will receive packets from the 
         * libpcap loop. 
         **************************************************************************/  
        PcapPacketHandler<String> jpacketHandler = new PcapPacketHandler<String>() {  

            public void nextPacket(PcapPacket packet, String user) {  

                System.out.printf("Received packet at %s caplen=%-4d len=%-4d %s\n",  
                    new Date(packet.getCaptureHeader().timestampInMillis()),   
                    packet.getCaptureHeader().caplen(),  // Length actually captured  
                    packet.getCaptureHeader().wirelen(), // Original length   
                    user                                 // User supplied object  
                    );  
            }  
        };  

        /*************************************************************************** 
         * Fourth we enter the loop and tell it to capture 10 packets. The loop 
         * method does a mapping of pcap.datalink() DLT value to JProtocol ID, which 
         * is needed by JScanner. The scanner scans the packet buffer and decodes 
         * the headers. The mapping is done automatically, although a variation on 
         * the loop method exists that allows the programmer to sepecify exactly 
         * which protocol ID to use as the data link type for this pcap interface. 
         **************************************************************************/  
        pcap.loop(10, jpacketHandler, "jNetPcap rocks!");  

        /*************************************************************************** 
         * Last thing to do is close the pcap handle 
         **************************************************************************/  
        pcap.close();  
    }  
}
```

This example was extracted from the jNetPcap website. As you can see, you just have to customize the nextPacket() method to make what you are intending.

That would simply be:

```
            public void nextPacket(PcapPacket packet, String user) {  

            Http http = new Http();  

            if (packet.hasHeader(http)) {  

                System.out.printf("Received packet at %s: %s\n",  
                    new Date(packet.getCaptureHeader().timestampInMillis()),   
                    http.Request.valueOf("Host")
                    );  

            }
```

Hope I've helped.

Comment: Fantastic. Unfortunately there's a bug where you can't get RequestURL from a packet, but it was easy to write my own method for this. Thank you very much!

Comment: I am glad it helped you. Share your workaround with us, so you can help other people.